# WHY ALWAYS initialize 19 cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm learning about TableView in Swift. My teacher give me this question: "You have 20 cells, but the screen shows 3 cell. How many cells have been initialized, and why?

This is my code. I tried with more than 20 cells, it's always initialized 19 cells. Can someone explain to me why? Thank you very much
I test on iPhone 11 ProMax, iOS 13.1

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTable.register(UINib(nibName: "ContactCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContactCell")
        myTable.dataSource = self
        myTable.delegate = self
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Superhero"

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return myTable.frame.size.height / 3.0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.section)
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
```

This code on another file

```
    class ContactCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var cellShow: UIView!
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            print("awakeFromNib")
        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        }  
    }
```

Comment: how do you know it's initializing 19 cells, show me where you saw that it's doing that. i ask this because you don't know that it's doing that unless you have another function that is parsing visible cells in the table view or traversing the view tree to cont them manually in debugger. how do you know it's 19?

Comment: It's because only the cells are being initialized that fit on your screen. Proof: try rotating your device – it'll be less (assuming you're going from portrait to landscape).

Comment: You can see in func awakeFormNib. i print "awakefromNib" when a cell was initialized. Then i count. if i retunn 100 cells, always print 19 lines "awakefromNib"

Comment: @Kevin.D that's not how this works, that has nothing to do with how many cells are being held in memory.

Comment: I think LinusGeffarth right. I tried on iphone 8 is 15 cells, iphone 11 pro is 17 cells

Comment: and LinusG could be right, but in the question you stated that the cells are 1/3 of the screen and the height is myTable.frame.size.height / 3.0, thatmeans only 3 cells are visible at a time

Comment: You right, Loxx. He wants me to know how reuse works. He tells me try with 3 cells, 3,5 cells

Comment: As @Loxx implied, your teacher's question is flawed in so many ways that virtually any attempt for an answer could be wrong (with the appropriate interpretation) (e.g. are you using prefetching? what os version? how many unique reuse identifiers? what does _cell initialization_ really means in this context etc.).

Comment: @Alladinian :)) That is reason i spent 2 week for that simple code. btw thank you guys so much. It help me a lot

Comment: In fact, this is so vague, that I could argue that `24` _is_ a correct answer and would [challenge him to prove me wrong](https://gist.github.com/alladinian/9b49b95f298f4ab25df9db0e9717a73e) :P

Comment: While I agree the question is vague, perhaps that's intentional... *"How many cells have been initialized, and **why**?"* The "why" part is more important than the "how many" part.

Comment: I think he wants to hear; singe cell is initialized per reuse identifier and gets reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's Docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview):

> Before it appears onscreen, the table view calls this method for the items in the visible portion of the table. As the user scrolls, the table view calls the method for items only when they move onscreen. It calls the method each time the item appears onscreen, regardless of whether it appeared onscreen previously.

During layout, the table view will start populating. During this process, sizes for elements are being determined. Depending on the initial height of your cell and the height of the table view, `heightForRowAt` can be called first for rows that *may* appear, then for rows that *probably* will appear, then for rows that *will* appear (and rows that may be just-off-screen).

Add a `print()` statement to your `heightForRowAt` func as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // add this line
    print(indexPath)

    return myTable.frame.size.height / 3.0
}
```

On my quick test, if 7 *default height* rows would fit based on my table view's height, I see this in the debug output:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 3]
[0, 3]
[0, 3]
[0, 4]
[0, 4]
[0, 4]
[0, 5]
[0, 5]
[0, 5]
[0, 6]
[0, 6]
[0, 6]
```

As you can see, ***7 cells*** are being initialized, with `heightForRowAt` being called 3 times for each cell.

**Edit:** ugh... zero-based... changed wrong *6* to correct *7*

---

Additional notes...

If you set `.estimatedRowHeight`, for example:

```
myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

you will see ***fewer*** cells being initialized, and with:

```
myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 10
```

you will see ***more*** cells being initialized, as auto-layout will use that value as the initial row heights rather than the default row height.

Also, if you want to understand a bit more about how cells are **reused**, add this to your `didSelectRowAt` handler (this is just a debug / dev feature, probably not useful for production code):

```
let reusableCells = tableView.value(forKey: "_reusableTableCells")
print(reusableCells as Any)
```

In my case (without setting `.estimatedRowHeight`), I get:

```
Optional({
    ContactCell =     (
        "<MyTest.ContactCell: 0x7fd0ccc295b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 300; 295 100); text = 'Superhero'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000010fecc0>>",
        "<MyTest.ContactCell: 0x7fd0ccc2a2a0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 400; 295 100); text = 'Superhero'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000010ff0c0>>",
        "<MyTest.ContactCell: 0x7fd0ccc2ad90; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 500; 295 100); text = 'Superhero'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000010ff4a0>>",
        "<MyTest.ContactCell: 0x7fd0ccc2ba80; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 600; 295 100); text = 'Superhero'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000010ff8a0>>"
    );
})
```

Note that the number of cells in the "reusable pool" will change as you scroll up and down.

**Another Edit:**

Also worth experimenting with... change this line in `cellForRowAt`, from:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "Superhero"
```

to:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "Superhero \(indexPath.row)"
```

Now, when selecting a row and printing out the "reusableCells" you can see which cells are actually in the "pool." My result changes to:

```
Optional({
    ContactCell =     (
        "<MyTest.ContactCell: 0x7fef77608330; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 300; 295 100); text = 'Superhero 3'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003d36d20>>",
        "<MyTest.ContactCell: 0x7fef776091b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 400; 295 100); text = 'Superhero 4'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003d37120>>",
        "<MyTest.ContactCell: 0x7fef7760a030; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 500; 295 100); text = 'Superhero 5'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003d37500>>",
        "<MyTest.ContactCell: 0x7fef7760aeb0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 600; 295 100); text = 'Superhero 6'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003d37920>>"
    );
})
```

Showing me that cells for rows 4, 5, 6 and 7 (as shown in the `text =` property --- again, zero-based) were initialized and are in the "reuse pool".

Comment: Thank you. It's really helpful

Comment: True but `cellForRowAt` prints exactly 18 cells for iPhone 11. I can only assume, before the auto layout engine kicks in table view assumes default height for the cells  (44pt) which will result in 812/44 = 18 whole cells.

Comment: @Desdenova - see my edits for clarification and some additional info.