# Why UITableView create redundant reuse cell if call [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:index animated:YES]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The number of cells is 30, scroll to 15 after 5 seconds in viewDidLoad. UITableView will create a redundant reuse cells after scrolling to the invisible cell.

[image: ScreenShot]

**Code:**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.frame;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
    
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 52;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(UITableViewCell.class)];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:15 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
    });
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(UITableViewCell.class)];
    cell.backgroundColor = [self.class randomColorWithAlpha:1];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Anyone should be able to reproduce it

Comment: This should explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541582/why-always-initialize-19-cells

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

hope to understand your question well.

UITableViewController in Objective-c is responsible for getting data that you want to display inside cells. In most cases, in fact, it is the "data delegate".

Well, in order to save memory and resources Objective-C automatically "reuses" cells that have been previously allocated. This means that the first cell in your Table will be the only one to be use memory. To display all the other cells, the TableViewController will work on the first one allocated.

It is NOT efficient to allocate every single cell. TableView(s) are often used to display dinamic content, so imagine that your program needs to allocate 150 different UITableViewCell(s): your application will probably crash or be slow.

As you can see here:

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(UITableViewCell.class)];`

you call 'dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier', where the word 'reusable' means what i said before.

Let me give you a little suggestion for well-structured projects:

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { //here call a method that returns you the number of elements you want to display }`

It is NOT a good practice to return a constant value such as 30. Always make sure that the number of rows in section is equal to the number of elements you want to display.